# How to analyze the filesize of an exe built with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, filesize, delphi-10-seattle

I would like to have a report that explains clearly why an exe built with Delphi has a specific size.

For example something like this:

```
filename: Project1.dpr - total size 100MB
   Details:
    - unit1.dcu - 20MB
    - unit2.dcu - 60MB
    - libraries.dcu - 20MB
```

I'd like to have this kind of report to understand why an exe i just built is 120MB in size. It uses many files from another application that when built is 90MB. I added just two units (and removed many) and the size changed from 90 to 120 MB. I was expecting a smaller size (considering many removed units).

is there some tool that already does this or is there a way to study this issue from the IDE?

Comment: Have you removed debug information from project options? It will reduce the file size, it should be under the linking section

Comment: @villekrumlinde wrote a tool to analyze the size of the units in an exe file: [delphiunitsizes](https://code.google.com/archive/p/delphiunitsizes/).

Comment: @LURD the tool does what i need, if you post a answer i will accept it. thanks

Comment: @AlbertoMiola your comment is very god too. I have debug info and if iremove it the size is 50% anyway in  both projects i am using debug info (since i use eurekalog) so still the problem is not solved. By using the tool delphiunitsizees at first glance i do not see fat units, i will studymore.

Comment: Are you perhaps using generics? Using of generics can significantly increase the EXE size.

Comment: Remove debug info. You don't need to ship that with the product.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but can i use EurekaLog without debuginfo?

Comment: @SilverWarior i am not using generics, in fact i use generics in one of the units i removed from the project

Comment: Surely you can. You build the debug info but don't link it into the executable. Then you reconstruct detailed stack traces from the information that you captured at build time. That's how it goes with madExcept. Surely Eureka doesn't force you to ship the debug info to the client. Any madExcept is better!

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to have a report that explains clearly why an exe built with Delphi has a specific size.

[Ville Krumlinde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43673/ville-krumlinde) wrote a tool that reports the unit sizes in an exe file by parsing the map file, created by the linker: [DelphiUnitSizes](https://code.google.com/archive/p/delphiunitsizes/).

[image]

Set `Project Options|Linking|Map File` to `Publics` or `Detailed` and make a full build of the exe. Open the resulting map file with `DelphiUnitSizes`.

Another similar tool is [MapFileStats](https://www.delphitools.info/other-tools/mapfilestats/) by Eric Grange.

---

> can i use EurekaLog without debuginfo?

From [EurekaLog documentation](https://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/index.php?configuring_project_itself.php):

> "Debug Information" (Linker page, new Delphi)/"Include TD32 debug info" (old Delphi)/"Full debug information" (C++ Builder) - this option embeds debug information for external debugger in TD32 format into your application. You may need this option if you use "Run"/"Attach to process" and Delphi can not find debug information. Also, EurekaLog uses TD32 info to complete missing information in C++ Builder. Note, that size of your Delphi application can increase 5-10 times by enabling this option (C++ Builder writes information in separate .tds file), unless you enable "Place debug information in separate TDS file" option.

And

> "Map file" - by enabling this option you tell the Delphi's linker to create a separate .map file along with your executable. Map file contains human-readable representation of debug information. Different settings for this option controls the detalization level of output. Usually, there is no need to change it to anything, which differs from "Off" or "Detailed". The map-file is used by various tools as primary source of debug information. For example, EurekaLog automatically turns this option on and uses map-file to create a debug information in its own format and then injects it into application. That is why you rarely need to change this option manually.

This means that the map file is injected in a way into the exe file, while including full debug information into the exe is optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind reading a little hex, you can set **Map file** to **Segments** in Project options - Delphi Compiler - Linking. You will get a text file named *yourexe*.map which contains a list of the included modules and their respective lengths.

This allows for a basic analysis of the contents of your exe. However, it will not answer your next question, "Do I really need all of this stuff?"...